# Fullpage.js with background colour fade

Tags: javascript, css

Hi I'm trying to get 2 plugins to work so that when you scroll there's a 'slide' transition from one full page container to another along with a background color fade transition.

**Plugins**

*Magic scrolling colour*
http://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/zBGBJV

*Fullpage.js* 
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

However the 'magic scrolling colour' doesnt seem to work if I contain all the ".panel" divs in any other tag/div other than  - the issues is that I need a container div in order for fullpage.js to work.

Even if I change the background colour js to target that container div name 
(i.e. )

```
$body = $('#fullpage') or $body = $('fullpage')
```

...it still won't work. I find it hard to believe it wouldn't work with anything between the variable divs and body tag.
I've mocked up an example of the issue here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmbmMm

I would be grateful if you could offer any assistance!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have

```
#fullpage {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

and

```
.color-indigo {
  background-color: #4332CF;
}
```

In CSS ID's have a higher priority than classes, so it overrides the custom color always. Easy fix, change the classes to

```
#fullpage.color-indigo {
  background-color: #4332CF;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get he's using `f4f4f4`?

Comment: @Alvaro from the original version of his codepen. The code is now different... but also working.

Comment: he's not using fullpge.js in his codepen. No initialization. So the code is irrelevant there.

Comment: @Alvaro as I said, he changed the content of the pen, it was different yesterday when I saw it. The code didn't work as expected because he had the issue from my answer. Yes, I see that he's not using fullPage.js now, but I still do think this answer might hold value for him.

Answer (score 0):

The `scroll` event won't get fired in fullPage.js unless you use the fullPage.js options `scrollBar:true` or `autoScrolling:false` as detailed in [the fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions).

So, you need scroll bar in order to register the `scroll` event that is being used by Magic Scrolling Color.

If you do not want to use a scroll bar and just want to recreate a fading effect, I would encourage you to go for the [fullPage.js Fading Effect extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/fading-effect.html).